# kendo mvvm - "set" will overwrite bindings

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI's MVVM framework for some things, and am encountering a frustrating and undesirable behavior with the way it sets observables and observable arrays.

Essentially, if you use the `set` function to set an Observable or ObservableArray to something new, existing binding events on that object are lost. I have some code here to show, and a jsBin to demonstrate.

## jsBIN

### [Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/UkAGiLe/1/edit)

## HTML

```
<div id="binding-content">
  <button data-bind="click: onUpdate">Update</button>
</div>
```

## MVVM

```
var viewModel = new kendo.observable({
    Id: "models/1",
    Name: "First Model",
    Consumable: false,
    Equipable: false,
    Mutations: [],
    Tags: [],
    onUpdate: function (e) {
        // first, do a simpler change to the mutations
        // so that we are not overwriting them
        var current = viewModel.get("Mutations");
        current.push({
            Id: "items/1",
            Value: "test"
        });
        current.push({
            Id: "items/2",
            Value: "test2"
        });

        // we will see the 'changed' message twice,
        // once for each item pushed into it.

        // now, just use the 'set' function
        // to completely replace the array
        viewModel.set("Mutations", [{
            Id: "items/1",
            Value: "test"
        }]);

        // we do not get a third changed event, because
        // the set function overwrote the array. We will
        // try to add things the old fashioned way again
        current = viewModel.get("Mutations");
        current.push({
            Id: "items/3",
            Value: "test3"
        });
        current.push({
            Id: "items/4",
            Value: "test4"
        });
    }
});

viewModel.Mutations.bind("change", function (e) {
    console.log('changed');
});

kendo.bind($("#binding-content"), viewModel);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `change` event bubbles up - instead of binding the change event for `Mutations`, why don't you bind to the top-level view model and then inspect the event to see which field triggered the change:

```
viewModel.bind("change", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.field + ' changed');
});
```

Edit:

If you really think you need to bind to the inner ObservableArray, then you can "replace" the array by removing all elements and adding the new one, so instead of

```
viewModel.set("Mutations", [{
    Id: "items/1",
    Value: "test"
}]);
```

you could do

```
current.splice(0, viewModel.Mutations.length); // remove existing items
current.push({
    Id: "items/1",
    Value: "test"
});
```

This would preserve your `change` bind (but it may be slower).

Comment: Wouldn't that just get overwritten too, though?

Comment: @Ciel not by calling `viewModel.set("Mutations", val);`, which I thought was the problem

Comment: Yeah, this does solve it. At least partially. This kind of ruins the purpose of having bindings at all. But it at least makes something usable, I suppose.

Comment: @Ciel how does it ruin it? This isn't really a Kendo UI specific issue - if you make changes to an object and then replace it with another one, the changes you made for the first object won't be in the new object, even if the new object is referenced by the same property.

Comment: @Ciel I added another alternative